# Calling a WCF web service from a SharePoint 2013 Visual Studio Workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2012, wcf

I have a scenario where I need to access a WCF web service (locally hosted) from a SharePoint 2013 Visual Studio workflow. Below given is what I have done so far:

**This is what the workflow does:**

[image]

**This is my Variables List**

[image]

**This is the message in the 1st WriteToHistory**

[image]

**This is the property window of 'BuildDynamicValue'**

[image]

**The HTTPSend activity and its propertie are shown below:**

[image]

**RequestHeaders Property of the WCF call**

[image]

**Final WriteToHistory's Message**

[image]

**The Code Behind of the WCF Services are shown below:**

IService1.cs Data Contract

[image]

Service1.cs Method Implementation

[image]

DTOTest class

[image]

**What Should Happen?:** The 2nd WriteToHistory should write 'You Accessed the WCF service" message taken from the WCF service.

Please Help!

** ******UPDATE 1:****** **

I manage to get a REST web service running with methods using json. How can I get the values of a custom class object returned by the REST web service. This is what I get on the browser when I hit the web service uri.

> {"GetDTOTestResult":{"DateTimeNow":"The DTOTest was returned at 9/15/2014 10:28:49 AM","Message":"Sample Message"}}

How can I get the DateTimeNow property via the GetDynamicValueProperties activity?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @Aanchal No error.. The History list shows nothing written for the 2nd WriteToHistory

Comment: I noticed in the 'RequestHeaders Property of the WCF call' you have the Method set to 'POST', should that be a 'GET'?  
  
Also, what happens if you try to hit the web service url directly from the browser?

Comment: @OmarStewey the 'GET' method did not work.. When I hit the web service url directly, I got a HTTP 400 Bad request error. However if i remove the '/GetDateTimeNow' part from the url and hit it. It works fine!

Comment: Any thoughts guys???

Comment: @Aanchal Please see my update on the question.. Thanks!

Comment: @OmarStewey Please see my update on the question.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution... I had to mention

> GetDTOTestResult/DateTimeNow

as the path for the property in the GetDynamicValueProperties activity.

Answer (score 1):

Since this popped up again being refreshed by Community account, I want to summarize the general idea of what you need to do:

**Workflow Side**

1. Use DynamicValue to represent a JSON object to be passed into a
   REST-service.  Also, DynamicValue to receive return values from a
   REST-service.
2. Use 'BuildDynamicValue' action to add properties to the DynamicValue workflow variable.
3. Use 'GetDynamicValueProperties' to pull specific properties out from the DynamicValue workflow variable.  This is also how you can walk the JSON object graph.
4. In general, DynamicValue can not be logged easily to history, which has a *tiny* character limit of 255 characters.  Try push them into a file in a document library for debugging.  Or limit logging to first 250 characters.
5. The property path is similar to XPath:  Result/Value1

**Service Side**

1. On WCF service side, use `[WebGet]` for GET requests.  Use `[WebInvoke]` for POST requests.
2. POST Requests are more suitable for multiple parameters, in which case, you want to wrap `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest` at least the Request.

   [WebInvoke(BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, UriTemplate="/GetHello", ...] 
   string GetHello(string hello, string world);

Call it like this:

```
POST { 
    url: '/GetHello', 
    data: { 
        'Hello': 'hello', 
        'World': 'world' 
    } 
}
```

Comment: WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest?  I used Bare.

Comment: Bare is fine if you are not passing arguments to the method.  If you are calling

[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, UriTemplate = '/GetHello', RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json]
string GetHello(string hello, string world);

Call it like this:

POST {
  url: '/GetHello',
  data: {
    'Hello': 'hello',
    'World': 'world'
  }
}

Comment: This is how we did the method with 2 parameters.. Please check if it's ok or can it be better than this?

[OperationContract]
        [WebGet(
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "GetSupervisorGroupName/{employeeID}/{companyName}")]
        string GetSupervisorGroupName(string employeeID, string companyName);